# How do i delete an OS fully

Tags: command-line, windows, bios

I have windows on a USB and when I plug it in it boot windows 10 but when I try to install it says I don't have space so I'm like ok maybe its because I still have my other os so I went to delete it from bios many because for some reason t won't boot  when I try to boot it takes me to the root command line and so I don't know how to delete my anonymous os entry/boot and I need help

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You've given no clues as to why you've asked here, or provided no details that are on-topic for this site*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format (erase) the hard drive.

You can do this easily using the Disks application on Ubuntu from a live session (The "Try Ubuntu" option from bootable installation media).

Select the hard drive and choose the option "Format..."

This will effectively remove **everything** on the target volume.